# How can I set server request timeout to 30 seconds limit in local for ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, request, limit, server-response

I'm debugging a issue for production.

Where the request takes more than `30s` and it fails.

I'm trying to reproduce the issue on my local machine.

How can I set the request timeout to `30s` in local.

Working on `Ruby on Rails` Application with `puma`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rack-timeout](https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout) gem.

Best,
Théo